# Put row names into a dataframe or a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I want to make the names of the rows into a vector. All of the information in the columns if now not reverent but when I remove it it obviously also removes the row names. Also as my now names are my index here im not sure how to get them out of the dataframe.

```
df
            Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
london      8  0  8  0  
paris       14  0  8  0  
beijing     14  0  8  0 
new_york    64 32 16 64 
rome        32  0  0  0  
berlin      12  0  6 16
```

What im looking for here is to remove all column information so that I am left with a vector like so;

```
london, paris, beijing, new_york, rome, berlin
```

(It doesn't have to be in that exact format)

Comment: use `rownames(df)`

Comment: or `row.names(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy as `row.names(df)`. So easy that I have to enter this to please SO minimum answer length.